# Applicative style understanding

Tags: haskell, applicative

I would like to write something as the following:

```
(+) <$> Just 3 <*> Just 5 <*>' (+) <*> Just 6
```

However the problem is that I need to somehow `flip` `<*>`. What is the idiomatic way in Haskell to do the type of chaining I'm trying?

Comment: Are you trying to sum a list of `Num a => Maybe a` values? If so, then `fmap sum . sequence` should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<**>` from [`Control.Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:4) is `flip <*>`. Your example can work with that, slightly rearranged:

```
>((+) <$> Just 3 <*> Just 5) <**> ((+) <$> Just 6)
Just 14
```